# can we create a virtual machine on azure using php sdk zip file

Tags: php

I am a project developer and I am creating a virtual machine on aws cloud using php coding by using aws sdk zip file. Is it possible to create a virtual machine on azure using azure php sdk zip file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

The Azure [`create vm deployment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj157194.aspx) service is wrapped by the PHP sdk :

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php/blob/master/WindowsAzure/ServiceManagement/ServiceManagementRestProxy.php#L994